# wallpaper & drivers for dell latitude E5510

Tags: laptop, drivers, desktop-customization

I am looking for the original wallpaper for the Dell Latitude E5510.

I installed Windows7 64-bit and I don't find the fingerprint driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drivers here

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs

Looks like you made a post on the Dell forums, maybe someone there will have a copy.
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19351605.aspx

Some original wallpapers here, 6 pages worth
http://www.bay-wolf.com/wpview.htm

Dell has some wallpapers, just none for the latitude
http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=3B236B92DC5A4186E040A68F5B287CA1

http://search.dell.com/results.aspx?s=dhs&c=us&l=en&cs=19&k=wallpaper&cat=all&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to get the fingerprint driver from the Dell website.  Go to Technical Support, enter in your express code and it should display all the updated drivers for that laptop.

Unfortunately, you'll be out of luck with the wallpaper.  You may get somewhere if you send Dell (tech support or customer service) an email requesting it.  That's probably your only chance there.

Good luck.